# How to creat different group of geofences for Windows phone 8.1 WRT

Tags: windows

I am working on a project and i need 3 different group of geofences where each of them execute a different function when entered. Can this be done and how or is there another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible - You are allowed to set up one Geofence or more.

The Windows 8.1 Sample App file includes a sample file for Geolocation with Windows Phone 8.1 that you might find helpful - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-2483de66

This is supported in Windows Phone 8.1 though there will be slight changes in 10. For details (and a step by step) they are on MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn263744